# Measuring input voltage with 3.3V ADC MCU

Tags: analog, adc, voltage-divider, protection, voltage-measurement

I am designing my very first DC motor driver circuit. Right at the start, I want to be able to measure the input voltage to the system. The system supposed to work with external DC power supply from 12 to 35 Volts. I think it is possible to directly measure this range with the ADC of the MCU (it is an STM32) with ADC ref voltage of 3.3V. Is the divider circuit below enough?

Do I need to do any protection for the MCU pin? Do I need to add a series resistor in the path between this (VSENSE_IN) point and the MCU pin?

For example, if the divider gives more than 5V...the MCU pin input limit is reached and damaged...how can I protect it from over voltage?

[image]

How can I improve this?

Comment: Well, just do calculations,

Comment: @g_1_k Calculation is correct...I just want to know if this the correct approach and if I need to add more components for protection e.g. Over Voltage.

Comment: if the divider gives more than 5V...the MCU pin input limit is reached and damaged...how can I protect it from over voltage?

Comment: Try looking up Zener diode, even though I think this is overkill for your application and that this setup will solve the problem

Comment: Recheck Calc results, I get 2.24V from 35V in.  But MCU inputs have Schottky diodes clamp overvoltage with <5mA limited OK by 82k.  For a full-scale Vin ADC use  gain and offset Vref to  Op Amp to convert 12~35V to 0 to 3.3V

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks. So you mean the ADC pins of STM32L476 already have clamping diodes? Then I do not need to do anything in this cae right? and that 82k resistor is big enough to limit the current to less than 20mA as per STM32 recommended sink/source currents?

Comment: Not the 20mA output current, I said MCU inputs... for over Voltage induced current. The ESD diodes are tiny and fast so usually rated for 5mA DC and high pulse. So a large series R input is good protection as well as a small RF cap. Change R value for 3.3V instead of 2.2

Comment: You can add a Zener to protect your IC in case the voltage goes higher or electrostatics. You can also add a high value resistor between your measuring node and the IC pin, you can put a smaller cap after that to further reduce noise.

Comment: the 20mA source/sink is not related to clamping diodes. Clamping diodes are there for electrostatic, but they are very low power and you shouldn't rely on them to clamp a voltage on your input pin.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a Zener to protect your IC in case the voltage goes higher or electrostatics. You can also add a high value resistor between your measuring node and the IC pin, you can put a smaller cap after that to further reduce noise.

[image]

Comment: Downvote can at least give a reason

Comment: Voltage divider will not be accurate when you are using uA, micro controller needs to graw current too. Zener diode will give false reading when it starts to draw current starting at 3V according to data sheet, could be even lower but not specify.

Comment: This is a reference schematic, the values needs to be calculated accordingly to the sense circuit and need of the application. Zener will conduct only when over-voltage in order to protect the UC, which in this case is 3.3V, it won't false anything since anyway the ADC will be saturated above the range.